# React native запись голоса

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

Как на react native реализовать запись голоса, и в какие-то интервалы времени иметь доступ к записанным данным, и как-то с ними работать, допустим отправлять на бекенд?

Comment: Взять плагин, как пример вот этот https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player и читать его документацию, разбираться как он работает и что куда пишет.